# Automake: Syntax of conditionals in Makefile.am

Tags: linux, makefile, automake

I am familiar with the `if VAR_NAME`, where `VAR_NAME` is defined by an AM_CONDITIONAL clause inside of configure.ac.

Is there a corresponding "if not defined" construct in Makefile.am?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no "if not defined" construct.  The configure.ac must be written so that the conditional is always defined.  However, you can do "if ! VAR_NAME" if you want to test that the condition is false.